# Counting words in a string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to count the occurrence of each word in a long string of text after filtering out some characters such as "!"#$%&'()*,-./:;?@[]_" and I did that using regex.

And reformating the output to be separated with a tab

so I faced two problems:

1- using return in the function only produced the first line yet when substituted with the print function it worked fine. Yet I fear using print instead of return.

2- on the TMC server, it returns an error that I don't understand.

Error:-

```
Failed: test.test_word_frequencies.WordFrequencies.test_first
        'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Test results: 1/2 tests passed
 50%[????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????]
```

Here is my progress so far:-

```
def word_frequencies(file):
    import re
    from collections import Counter

    counts = []
    inputfile = open(file,"r")
    textfile = inputfile.read()
    pattern = re.compile(r'([\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\,\-\\.\\\/\:\;\?\@\[\]\_])')
    file_clean = re.sub(pattern,"",textfile)
    words = file_clean.split()
    for word in words:
        counts.append(Counter(words)[f'{word}'])
    for word,count in zip(words,counts):
        print(f"{word}\t{count}")
```

I'm not sure if using a return function at the last for loop was wise as it returns:-

```
'The\t64'
```

Instead of:-

```
The 64
Project 83
Gutenberg   27
EBook   3
of  303
Alice   166
etc...
```

I'm not sure where this error is coming from.

Comment: `return` exits the function, so you're not going to see any further output from a loop after it hits a `return` instruction the first time. If you want your function to return a collection of data, create an array, list, map, etc. within your function, add to it within your loop, and return the collection object at the end.

Comment: Also, you don't need to escape every character that isn't part of the alphabet. The pattern you posted above can be simplified to `r"[!\"#$%&'()*,.\\/:;?@[\]_-]"`.

Comment: Thank you for the simplification of the regex yet i had to escape the ' too since i use single quotes yet i got the concept thank you

Comment: on another note, if I use a list as an output it won't return single strings per line but a list and somehow doesn't interpret the \t correctly

Comment: I used a for loop for this :
`
for word,count in zip(words,counts):
    result.append(f"{word}\t{count}")
print(result)
`
yet it returns a list of :
`
['The\t64', 'Project\t83', 'Gutenberg\t27', 'EBook\t3', 'of\t303', 'Alice\t166', 'in\t214', 'Wonderland\t3', 'by\t44', 'Lewis\t3', 'Carroll\t3', 'This\t13', 'eBook\t6', 'is\t62', 'for\t64', 'the\t735', 'use\t12', 'of\t303']
`

Answer (score 0):

Return statement is returning what you are appending to the list.

In your example,

```
for word,count in zip(words,counts): 
    result.append(f"{word}\t{count}")
print(result)
```

It's the print statement, you are printing list instead of element itself. Try below

```
for data in result:
    print(data)
```

Comment: I did use a similar concept in the main question above


`for word in words:
        counts.append(Counter(words)[f'{word}'])
    for word,count in zip(words,counts):
        print(f"{word}\t{count}")`

Comment: isn't that the same thing?